# Has anyone used Open Office embedded in a .NET Desktop Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, openoffice.org

Is there a way to embed OpenOffice inside a .NET Application?

Something like the use of the [DsoFramer](http://codebetter.com/blogs/paul.laudeman/archive/2006/05/25/Registration_2D00_Free-COM-with-the-DsoFramer-Control.aspx) in case of MS Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API for doing it,

http://www.opendocument4all.com/download/OpenOffice.net.pdf

The only thing I had to modify is that i couldn't fing the .dll in the directory it says on the PDF, I downloaded the Open Office SDK and there they are in the Basis\sdk\cli located  in the folder created by the Open Office under the [Program Files].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would do this considering open office is written in java. Although, since it is open source maybe you could write an embeddable version?